# get the height of layout which has wrap_content property

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple table and a `scrollView` for scrolling the `TableRow`. I had also added footer the problem is that i need to know what is the size of footer so I can give the `android:layout_marginBottom="<size of footerbar>` to my scrollView. So how can i get the height of the layout of footer bar? please help me.

this is my footerbar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/btnColor"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    style="@style/pagingBarBtnAttr"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/choose_color_btn"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/previous"
    android:text="Previous" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pageNo"
    style="@style/pagingBarBtnAttr"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Page No. 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    style="@style/pagingBarBtnAttr"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/choose_color_btn"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/next"
    android:text="Next" />
```

now as the next and previous button has a drawable so they have the drawable according to device size so the footer bar has no fixed value of its height so how can i get its height so i can supply that value to `margin_bottom` of `scrollview`. Thanks in advance..

Comment: can u post what u have done for the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code

First add **footer** in your xml file and set its **alignParentBottom** to true.

Then add scrollView and set its **layout_above** property with the footer id

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imgFooter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgFooter"
    android:layout_below="@id/nav_bar_header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="5dp" >
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i had tried that before as my layout is very complex it wasnt work at all but today it is working by applying ur logic..! thank you very much..

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewTreeObserver for your layout you used for footer

```
 ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //Here you can get dimension of view
                        //This method will called after screen created
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using View's getLayoutParams() method, and you can get the height from the params :)

Answer (score 1):

```
oldLayout = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
Width = oldLayout.width;
```