# get height of layout that is set to wrap content

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to get height of linear layout that is set to wrap content. but it is zero.
i try this codes:

```
 final LinearLayout below= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.below);


         ViewTreeObserver vto = below.getViewTreeObserver();  
         vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
             @Override  
             public void onGlobalLayout() {  
                  width  = below.getMeasuredWidth(); 
                  height = below.getMeasuredHeight();  

             }  
         });
```

and :

```
 LinearLayout below= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.below);
       final int belowh=below.getHeight();
```

using code:

```
 final LinearLayout below= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.below);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = below.getViewTreeObserver(); 
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onGlobalLayout() { 

        if(below.getMeasuredHeight()> 0){

                 this.below.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
                int width  = below.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = below.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        }
            } 
        })

    ;
```

[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4tkL.png)

Comment: you can refer this link once [get the height of layout which has wrap_content property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062401/get-the-height-of-layout-which-has-wrap-content-property)

Comment: you should call it after the view has been laid out...

Comment: @Md.ShahadatSarker thanks it works fine.

Comment: Try to avoid the use of thread...... if not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
final LinearLayout below= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.below);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = below.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onGlobalLayout() { 

    if(below.getMeasuredHeight()> 0){

             this.below.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
            int width  = below.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = below.getMeasuredHeight(); 
    }
        } 
    })

;
```

Comment: I tried it before but I don't know why below cannot be resolved in this line:              this.below.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

Comment: I have ediited my answer, please check now.

Comment: I add your code an again that problem. you can see what I mean in the question. I edited it add add a picture of it. click on that link to see what is the problem.

Comment: remove 'this' >> below.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

Answer (score 6):

Try this code for getting layout width and height after your view is created

```
final LinearLayout below= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.below);
    below.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.i("TAG", "Layout width :"+ below.getWidth());
                Log.i("TAG", "Layout height :"+ below.getHeight());
            }
    });
```

Hope this help

Comment: your code works well and also @Md. Shahadat Sarker segustion works-call it after the view has been laid out- but i don't know which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

@coder android

If you still stack on this.... please see this. I think this will work perfectly.

The following code is found [How to retrieve the dimensions of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/4406090#4406090)

```
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.image_test);
ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)tv.getBackground();
        ld.setLayerInset(1, 0, tv.getHeight() / 2, 0, 0);
        ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }

});
```